# How to update multiple records using records from another table with join

Tags: informix

I'm going to explain this scenario in such a way that it is easy to understand. For example I have 3 tables that I need to join in order to get the value I need for the age.

See below table structure with data :

```
table1:

name    age
----    ---
Mark    23
Sam     30

table2:

id      name
--      ----
1       Mark
2       Sam   
   
table3:

id      age
--      ---
1       40
2       23
```

I need to update the age from table3 in table1 using the data from table3 by using a join to achieve this.

Below is the query I tried using :

```
UPDATE table1 e
SET
e.age = b.age
FROM table2 a, table3 b
WHERE a.id = b.id
AND b.age != e.age
```

I get the below error :

```
-23911  Cannot update a row twice in a joined-row update.
```

If you do an update join, the join condition and any filters
must be sufficiently strict so that no row of the update target table
is produced more than once for updating. The error occurred because
the same row came around twice. The query was terminated abnormally.

Either clean the data source or sources, or make the query more restrictive
so that no target table row is produced more than once for updating.

What I am trying to achieve is below :

```
table1:

name    age
----    ---
Mark    40
Sam     23

table2:

id      name
--      ----
1       Mark
2       Sam   
   
table3:

id      age
--      ---
1       40
2       23
```

This is very simple table structure I am working with and basically what I am trying to achieve, but the real query I am working with is much more complicated. I have attempted examples from similar scenarios, but none of them works.

Below is the query I am trying to resolve or get working for this test:

```
UPDATE monitor:tab_last_change e
SET
e.records = b.nrows
FROM sysmaster:systabnames a, sysmaster:sysptnhdr b
WHERE a.partnum = b.partnum
AND a.tabname = e.tabname
AND b.nrows != e.records
```

The above still results in error -23911.

Answer (score 0):

The database is upset because `b.age != e.age` could match multiple records, hence if you have more rows in your table, each row could be a not-match several times.

You should secure the match first, and then decide whether to update,

```sql
UPDATE table1 e
SET e.age = b.age
FROM table2 a, table3 b
WHERE a.id = b.id AND A.NAME = E.NAME
AND b.age != e.age
```

Also, I'm not sure what DB you are using, to separate the logic layer, you may need to use the `JOIN` clause to match on name before excluding on age.